# Asp.net mvc identity current user path to razor view return error / The model item passed into the dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using asp.net identity 2.0 and trying to pass current user to razor view. Here is my code :

```
public ActionResult Settings()
{
    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var user = _db.Users.Find(currentUserId);

    return View(user);
}
```

But in razor i'm getting the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_D3D98E327FE171A79BDF8C79D31176E467C1EAF139BF185F0608911A37B99ECA', 
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ExamsTraining.Models.ExternalLoginListViewModel'.

It says that razor view needs ExternalLoginListViewModel but In razor i  have a model :

```
@model ExamsTraining.Models.User
```

I'm passing a correct model...

Comment: what do you need to get in the view? all user data? or just some?

Comment: I need all user data

Comment: See the following error

Comment: clean your project and rebuild and see what happens ? May be delete teh dlls from temp asp.net folder

Comment: When i was at work save files  on google drive  and then download it at home. Maybe it's a problem?

Comment: Clean but i am getting the same error

Comment: I've renamed settings to bla and correct page loaded, but problem still exists!! :

Comment: try follow this https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff/issues/122, and btw thanks for the downvote, people just trying to help.

Comment: Are there any `RenderPartial` or `Html.Partial` calls in your view?

Comment: Nope i think its'an identity framework bug. i've tryied to pass home/index current user but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your exception I assume that you are loading the wrong view.  Go to `Views/{Controller name folder}/Settings.cshtml` view and make sure that the correct model is there.

The problem could be deeper if you are using `Html.Partial` in view or layout.

Comment: I've checked on debugger and i'm loading a correct view,,,

Comment: Nope User Controller different from Account

Comment: Search in your project, in folder Views for ExternalLoginListViewModel and tell me where you found it

Comment: I've renamed settings to bla, but problem still exists!! :

Comment: try then return View("Settings", user)

Comment: In AccountViewModel and has only returnurl property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105194/discussion-between-volodymyr-bilyachat-and-user3857731).

Comment: Problem was Html.parial which was exists on layout page